# Determine deployed web application version

Tags: java, svn, maven, version

I am developing web application on Java platform using JSF, Maven build, SVN.

I have already included the application version number, revision, date extra on the jar/war manifest using maven plugin.

How can I find the version number of the deployed application from the browser using page view source (if I want hide this from the end user) ?

stackoverflow.com display the version details at the footer e.g. rev 2013.10.20.1076.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible alternative is as follows:

Use `versions:set -DnewVersion={{YOUR_VERSION_NUMBER}}` to set the version.

Then in the maven-war-plugin:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <your-version>${project.version}</your-version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Finally, you can use [jcabi-manifests](http://manifests.jcabi.com/index.html) to do further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this maven plugin :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Impossible de filtrer les ressources web de l'application avec le plugin v2.0.2 Nécessaire pour 'versioner' les .css, .js Maven 2.x WAR Plugin MWAR-134 -->
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Maven 2.x WAR Plugin MWAR-187 regression running war packaging with maven 2.1 Stephane Nicoll added a comment - 07/Jul/09 3:28 AM One way to quickly work around this issue is to deactivate the cache. -->
                <useCache>false</useCache>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <!-- Filtering activates replacement of ${pom.version} in *.xhtml... -->
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <!-- I've chosen to exlude manually these resources from the filtering -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then you can insert this in the base xhtml template for your application (well... in something that ends up in all your pages if you want it on all pages) :

```
<span style="display:hidden">${pom.version}"</span>
```

Note : this will work on a maven-built war. If you don't use maven while testing your webapp with Eclipse for instance, you'll still have `${pom.version}` not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some text static file with content:

```
version: ${pom.version}
build time: ${build.time}
svn revision: ${svn.revision}
svn path: ${svn.path}
committed date: ${svn.committedDate}
```

and put it to *src\main\webapp\about\info.txt*, use *com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin* to provide values for above variables:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            .......
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>svn-revision-number-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <entries>
                        <entry>
                            <prefix>svn</prefix>
                        </entry>
                    </entries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
              .....
     </plugins>
   .........
</build>
```

The file will be available under `http://your-domain.com/resources/about/info.txt`